# JQuery function not getting data attribute

Tags: jquery

I am using an external JQuery library called 3D RealFlipbook (from Codecanyon). It works great, but I'm trying now to generalize my solution to get the PDF url from using the 'data-pdf' attribute which is dynamic. However, it seems like the function cannot get the attribute when I click on my button. What am I doing wrong here?

Here's the code:

```
<button data-pdf=http://example.com/myPdfUrl.pdf" class="flipper">VIEW MAGAZINE</button>



$(".flipper").flipBook({
        pdfUrl: $(this).attr("data-pdf"),
        lightBox:true
    });
```

If I do the following, the attribute shows up properly:

```
$(".flipper").click({
            alert($(this).attr("data-pdf"))
        });
```

Comment: In `$(".flipper").flipBook({ pdfUrl: $(this).attr` (with no other provided details) - `this` will be `window`

Comment: @freedomn-m It doesn't work :/

Comment: What doesn't work? I've just commented on what the issue is, the answers are for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need element specific data to pass to a plugin a simple approach is initialize inside an `each()` loop where each individual element instance is exposed.

```
$(".flipper").each(function(){
    $(this).flipBook({
        pdfUrl: $(this).attr("data-pdf"),
        lightBox:true
    });
});
```

Comment: Brilliant, this works perfectly. Thanks! Question is, why does this one work and the other one doesn't?

Comment: Because the context of `this` in your approach is `window` or `document` whereas within `each` jQuery sets context as individual element